# using lambda expression and find_if on a collection

Tags: c++, stl, lambda

I have a container object :

```
R Container;
```

R is of type `list<T*>` or `vector<T*>`

I am trying to write the following function:

```
template<typename T, typename R>
T& tContainer_t<T, R>::Find( T const item ) const
{   
typename R::const_iterator it = std::find_if(Container.begin(), Container.end(),  [item](const R&v) { return item == v; });
if (it != Container.end())
    return (**it);
else
    throw Exception("Item not found in container");
}
```

When trying the method (v is an object of my class)

```
double f = 1.1;
v.Find(f);
```

I get `binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const double' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

I am confused with the lambda expression syntax and what i should write there and couldn't find any friendly explanation.

What is wrong ? 10x.

Comment: Would you consider writing the Find signature as accepting `(const T item)` instead of `(T const item)`? Or even better, use `const T &item`.

Comment: You are passing a `const R &` as argument to the lambda instead of a `const T*`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Missing a bit of context, but I note:

- You return `**it` so you possibly want to compare `*v==itemt`
- You pass `const R&v` where I suspect you meant `const T&v` into the lambda
- You used a const_iterator, but returned a non-const reference. That was a mismatch
- I made some params const& for efficiency (and to support non-copyable/non-movable types)

Here is working code, stripped of the missing class references:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename R=std::vector<T> >
T& Find(R& Container, T const& item ) 
{   
    typename R::iterator it = std::find_if(Container.begin(), Container.end(),  [&item](const T&v) { return item == v; });
    if (it != Container.end())
        return *it;
    else
        throw "TODO implement";
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<double> v { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    Find(v, 2.0); // not '2', but '2.0' !
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: trial an error led me to `typename R::const_iterator it = std::find_if(Container.begin(), Container.end(),  [item](const T* v) { return *v == item; });`

Comment: Can the spurious downvoter please explain him/herself :/